# A button that resets the function that creates a grid of divs

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and currently working on a project. I've created a 16x16 grid of divs using the DOM, and I'm currently in the process of trying to make a button that will allow me to reset those divs and prompt the user to resize it by asking how many total squares they would like to make. I'm having a hard time grasping the logic.

````
const container_Div = document.getElementById("container");
main_Body.appendChild(container_Div);
const grid_Div = document.createElement("div");
    grid_Div.className = "square";
const square = document.getElementsByClassName(".square");  
 
   
 
 
//Loop to create 32 divs for the 16x16 grid
function createDivs (amount){
   
    for(x=0;x <= amount; x++){
    const grid_Div = document.createElement("div");
    grid_Div.className = "square";
    container_Div.appendChild(grid_Div);
   
   //Color change
    grid_Div.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
            grid_Div.style.backgroundColor = "#303558"
            grid_Div.style.opacity = 1.0; })
 
}
}
 
createDivs(255);
 
 
 
//button div container
const btn_Div = document.createElement("div");
    btn_Div.className = "button-container";
    btn_Div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
 main_Body.insertBefore(btn_Div,container_Div);
 
 
 //actual button
 const myButton = document.createElement("button");
 myButton.className = "reset-prompt";
 myButton.textContent = "Reset and Resize";
 myButton.style.opacity = 1.0;
 
 btn_Div.appendChild(myButton);
 
 
 
 
//Function to clear the board
function eraseBoard(){
    createDivs(-1);
    let customDiv = prompt("How many squares you want chief?");
    createDivs(customDiv);
}
 
function buttonReset(){
    let button = document.getElementsByClassName(".reset-prompt");
    button.addEventListener("click", eraseBoard())
 
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your code, it looks as if you started with a simple problem and solved it.

Once that problem was solved, you created a harder problem and tried to jimmy its solution into your existing code. This is all of programming, and this is where it gets tricky. Your original createDivs function does not expect there to be anything on the board, so it behaves unexpectedly when you call it a second time. I expect if you call it with any positive number, it adds that number of new cells. If you call it with a negative number, it does nothing. This is because you didn't originally write it to be able to redraw the board.

There are a number of tools that people have developed to help them work through a process that is unfamiliar to them. The wikipedia page on [flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) provides a good run down on a lot of them. Personally, I find that simply writing the function's comments before its code helps me figure out what the code needs to be doing.
For example:

```js
function redrawBoard(size) {
  // Clear the board.
  // loop through cells.
    // Insert cell.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips - seems like I've made it harder on myself than it needed to be. I'll try to comment out my function first! Quick question: should I put the reset component WITHIN my createDiv function? Like in an If Statement (if that's even possible)?

Comment: A function called createDivs should never erase a div. My suggestion above was to call the function redrawBoard instead. That's mostly because in `eraseBoard()`, it looks like you are trying to clear the board with `createDivs(-1)`. That will not work because `createDivs`  does not (and should not) erase anything. The change that will require the least rework of your code will be to write a `clearDivs()` function that clears the board and call that instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Charles, I was able to finally get my button working as intended! I appreciate your support.